# Styling components and react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm fairly new to React and started checking out React-Bootstrap and the way the components are styled. The documentation clearly styles components with `variant`:

```
<Button variant="primary">Success</Button>
```

However, this code seems to work just as well with the traditional `className`. Functionally, and aesthetically, if I change the above code to something like,

```
<Button className="bg-primary">Success</Button>
```

the output is the exact same. Personally, I find using the `className` attribute much easier as I can write vanilla bootstrap classes like `btn btn-primary...` instead of different react-bootstrap classes.

Is there any functional difference between the two and is there a reason to use `variant` over `className`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between `variant` and `className`:

**Variant:**
- uses only pre-defined classes
- no need for an external library

**className:**
- can use custom classes
- works the same as the `HTML` attribute `class`

I personally use `className`

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use React-Bootstrap, preferring to include the CDN to Bootstrap and apply classes to my own components using `className`.

As far as I can tell, there is no functional difference between both methods.

Answer (score 0):

Variant is a prop for your **React-Bootstrap** components which wrap the various predefined styles for the different bootstrap components. You can't customise a React Bootstrap component using a variant(if you want to deviate from bootstrap's theme).

ClassNames are your normal CSS classes wherein you can add any style to components through CSS. The reason `className="bg-primary"` would work because React-Bootstrap has the bootstrap's css file included as part of the library.

Answer (score 0):

this is the bootstrap Button Component:

```
    const Button = props =>{
    const variant = props.variant?`btn-${props.variant}`:""
    return(
    <button className={`btn ${variant} ${props.className}`}
    onClick ={props.onClick}>
    </button>
    )
    }
```